# Highcharts equidistant scaling

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need [this chart](http://jsfiddle.net/fpanci/fybakpue/3/) looks like [this](http://imageshack.com/a/img912/5298/53Brtp.jpg).

The problem is that de axis points are not equidistant between axis.

I've tried to set the ordinal property to false but it doesn't work.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'spline'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Mohr'
        },
        xAxis: {
            tickInterval: 0.5,
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            min: 0
        },
        yAxis: {
            tickInterval: 0.5,
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            min: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Circ 1',
            marker: {
                    enabled: false
                },
            data: [[2.684809439972451,0.0],[2.6822125873590954,0.06609431256698768],(...more)]
        }, {
            name: 'Circ 2',
            marker: {
                    enabled: false
                },
            data: [[3.7570186145196027,0.0],[3.75431046351298,0.0689270458360995],(...more)]
        }, {
            name: 'Circ 3',
            marker: {
                    enabled: false
                },
            data: [[4.805153756251244,0.0],[4.802371412955787,0.0708153656825976], (...more)]
        }]
    });
});
```

I can not find the way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a need or benefit for using `tickPixelInterval` (or `minorTickInterval`) in this case.

The property is not precise, and the chart will still pick what it deems an appropriate value based somewhat on the value you provide.

All you have to do is make sure you set a min and max for each axis, as well as the `tickInterval`, so that you can control how many 'blocks' appear on each axis6.

Then set your container height and width accordingly to make sure that the block width is the same as their height.  Don't forget to account for chart margins (best way is to set them explicitly so you don't have to guess or calculate).

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/htkv6tu3/

There's no way the chart could natively determine that you would want the values of the x and y axes to be the same scale, and in most charts, that would be undesirable in fact.

Comment: Thanks again @jlbriggs. I think it would be nice to have a chart property that forces this such as equidistantScaling: true. Don't you think?

Comment: You can add a feature request here: http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general  I don't personally see a lot of use cases for it, though I can see how it's important in your case.